# Can I make a button do an NSDate comparison in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate

Is it possible to have an action from a button a) do an NSDate store when tapped, and then b) for that method to do a date comparison with an if statement?

So, for instance, if the stored NSDate was less than 12 hours ago, the user could not press the button again?

Haven't come across a tip on this from my research.

Comment: Buttons don't act.  You can have a method in the view controller do pretty much anything, though.

Comment: Where are you stuck? How to add a target / action to a button? How to persist a date? How to compare a date?

Comment: The action part is fine. It's doing a date comparison as part of the button method that was tripping me up.

Comment: But you'd have no trouble doing it if it weren't in a "button method"?

Comment: Actually, the process explained below did the trick for me. I just didn't really see what the relationship was, exactly. First app attempt and I was a bit lost. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can get current date by code

```
[NSDate date]
```

Then save him into [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

And check a current date with saved date on button press.

How

```
 if ( [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: savedDate] >= 12*60*60) // 12 hours
{    
// do your steps
}
```

Comment: You can just use `+[NSDate date]`

Comment: This looks great. Let me give that a go. Thanks for the speedy help.